# Convertir formato dd/MM/yy a dd/MM/yyyy, no funciona en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-10g

Tengo datos de tipo *varchar* que son fechas en formato DD/MM/YY y deben ser datos de tipo fecha en formato DD/MM/YYYY cuando hago la prueba:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('10/11/95') FROM DUAL
```

Retorna **10/11/1995** que es lo correcto pero al asignar esa fecha a una variable date retorna 10/11/2095.

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar el parseo correcto?

Comment: Hechale un vistazo a la función to_char, igual te puede servir de algo

Answer (score 1):

### Una columna de tipo **DATE** y una variable en PL/SQL de tipo **DATE** NO tienen formato.
Es una estructura interna de 8 bytes.

Lo que Ud. ve en pantalla, como por ejemplo "10/11/1995" depende de la configuración de la herramienta (como por ejemplo SQL*Plus, SQL Developer) que esté utilizando, y que está en el parámetro NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Si en la función TO_DATE no se usa el segundo parámetro que especifica el formato del STRING, entonces Oracle usa el default que tenga el parámetro NLS_DATE_FORMAT.
Por lo visto en el caso de la pregunta está configurado como DD/MM/RR, el RR significa que solo se digitan los 2 últimos números del año y Oracle aplica un año de quiebre (que cambia cada año) para determinar si es de los años 1900 o de los años 2000.

Para demostrar que un tipo DATE no tiene formato puede ejecutar los siguientes ejemplos:

```
select dump(to_date('2020-10-20','yyyy-mm-dd')) as volcado
from dual;
VOLCADO                          
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0



select dump(to_date('20-10-2020','dd-mm-yyyy')) as volcado
from dual;
VOLCADO                          
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0



select dump(to_date('10-20-20','mm-dd-rr')) as volcado
from dual;

VOLCADO                          
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0



select dump(to_date('octubre-20-20','MONTH-dd-rr')) as volcado
from dual;
VOLCADO                          
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0
```

Para conocer el formato de conversión en el parámetro "nls_date_format":

```
select value
from v$parameter a
where name='nls_date_format';
```

La respuesta depende de como haya configurado su herramienta, por ejemplo puede ser:
VALUE
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Entonces se puede usar

```
select dump(to_date('2020-10-20')) as volcado
from dual;
VOLCADO                          
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0


Pero si escribo la fecha como DD-MM-RR:

select dump(to_date('10-20-20')) as volcado
from dual;

Entonces sale el error:

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Si se cambio el formato usando lo siguiente:

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS'

Entonces si puede usar

```
select dump(to_date('20-10-20')) as volcado
from dual;

select dump(to_date('20-10-20')) as volcado
from dual;
```

VOLCADO
Typ=13 Len=8: 228,7,10,20,0,0,0,0

Lo mismo aplica para la función TO_CHAR

Si no se especifica el segundo parámetro con el formato para el string que construirá a partir de un valor tipo DATE entonces usa el valor por omisión del parámetro nls_date_format